# Object doesn't support this property or method in < I.E. 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm a JS noobie and I'm stumped by a bug that's coming up in < I.E 9. In all other browsers my app works fine. The user plugs in some values on a form and gets a title insurance quote returned. You can see the page at http://dailyspiro.com/

The following "var amount..." line returns the error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
var quantity = $('#amount').val();
var amount = quantity.replace(/\,/g,''); // removes commas in numeric string
```

The #amount div is a dropdown with numeric values. Since there were so many values on the dropdown (hundreds) I put the code for it in the JS file rather than the html doc. Here's a tiny excerpt of what it looks like:

```
var getAmount = function() {
$('#amount').html('<option value=""></option><option value="0">$0 to $30,000</option><option value="30,001">$30,001 to $35,000</option> <option value="35,001">$35,001 to $40,000</option> <option value="40,001">$40,001 to $45,000</option> <option value="45,001">$45,001 to $50,000</option>) 
}
```

I've seen other threads with this same error but can't figure out how it applies here. Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `quantity` when this happens?

Comment: The quantity depends on which value the user selects from the dropdown. I tested to make sure the JS pulls the value correctly from the dropdown so I don't think that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Does the error happen no matter which quantity the user selects?

Comment: All numbers except the lowest ones which don't have commas that need to be removed. I actually just added in the line  quantity = quantity.toString(); and it appears to be working

Comment: For some reason, `.val()` is returning an object instead of a string, I'm not sure why. I've never seen that.

Comment: There's another problem in your script: you set `location` even if no location is checked -- you need to check whether `where` is null first.

Comment: Yeah it's really bizarre. Sometimes I wish early versions of IE magically disappeared... :)

Comment: good catch Barmar, will correct that

Comment: You could also try upgrading jQuery. What it's returning is an array, which would be right if it were a multi-select. I see some changes in jQuery 1.9 in the code that decides whether it's a select-one or select-multi.